# How to redefine label within a command?

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to replace every occurrence of `\label` with a given command `\mylabel` but only within a given command `\mycommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mylabel[1]{Test}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\mycommand{This is a \label{tag1}.}\label{tag2}
\end{document}
```

So in this example the output should be `This is a Test.`.

Comment: The second `label` `tag2` is not really useful, in my point of view. And don't use `minimal` class

Comment: Thanks. The second tag was just to make clear that `Test` should not be output outside of `mycommand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to restrict some commands within a `group`, so a redefinition does not 'survive' the end of the group, fixing `\let\label\mylabel` here.

Be careful with specific redefinitions of the `\label` command that have an optional argument, e.g. the `\label`-version provided by `cleveref`, for example.

Outside of `\mycommand`, `\label` is acting as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mylabel[1]{Test}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\label\mylabel
  #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\mycommand{This is a \label{tag1}.}\label{tag2}
\end{document}
```

[image]